# I'm trying to populate my textboxes whenever I select an item in a listbox but I'm stuck with this error

Tags: c#, sql-server, listbox

I keep getting the error

> The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be found.

I have these codes

```
private void lbProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dtbProduct = dc.getDataTable(string.Format("SELECT P.product_id, P.product_name, P.product_price, T.[type_name], T.[type_fee], T.[type_id] FROM Product P INNER JOIN [Product Type] T ON P.[type_id] = T.[type_id] WHERE product_name = {0}", lbProduct.SelectedItem.ToString()));
            for (int i = 0; i < dtbProduct.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //P.TypeName = dtbProduct.Rows[i]["type_name"].ToString();
                txtPrice.Text = dtbProduct.Rows[i]["product_price"].ToString();
                txtProductName.Text = dtbProduct.Rows[i]["product_name"].ToString();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

..

```
public DataTable getDataTable(string query)
    {
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dtbProduct.Rows is null and it's blowing up when you try to iterate over it ... there is no count on a null object.  In any case, I am fairly certain that at least one issue is that you should be using bProduct.**SelectedValue** instead of bProduct.**SelectedItem**.

Comment: There could be more wrong with the query ... I can't test that.  Debug and get the exact sql statement your code is trying to execute, then take that and run it in Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) against your database.  I'm pretty sure it's going to fail and you should be able to have more of an idea why at that point.

Comment: I tried executng the query in ssms and it's working.

Comment: I would suggest debugging your code and being more specific about where exactly it's going off the rails.  There is too much of your code that nobody else can see.  Somehow that table is not coming back.